# How can branches get pruned in a query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

suppose I have a tree where certain nodes have a relationship of a give type, how would I return all nodes in the tree except for those with the given relationship ***and its descendants***.

I've gotten half way there with something like this (the tree is built on `has` links):

```
match (root: {Name: 'Root'})-[:has*]->(n) where not (n)-[:Exemption]-() return n
```

but, of course, this excludes nodes that have a relationship of type `Exemption` ***but not its descendants***, so the descendants show up as unconnected nodes

how do I structure the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some experimentation, this worked:

```
match (root: {Name: 'Root'})-[:has*]->(n)
match (m)-[:has*]->(n) 
where not (m)-[:Exemption]-() 
return n
```

which essentially says: find a path, for any node on that path, traverse back up to make sure that **none of the ancestors** show an exception.  so what I'm negating here is the subpath created with the second match

Answer (score 3):

This query should work:

```
MATCH p=({Name: 'Root'})-[:has*]->(n)
WHERE NONE(x IN NODES(p) WHERE (x)-[:Exemption]-())
RETURN n;
```

It filters out any `:has` relationship paths with a node that (also) has an `:Exemption` relationship.

Comment: this query came back empty, and I think the reason is that it looks at an entire path and says: if any of the nodes in that path should be eliminated, the whole path gets eliminated... which is not what I need.  I need to eliminate **only** the descendants of nodes I've tagged

Comment: Based on my understanding of your use case, this query works for me. Please provide a simple data sample in which this query does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably split the path up into two parts:

```
MATCH p=(:Label {Name: 'Root'})-[:has*]->(n) WHERE NOT EXISTS ((n)-[:Exemption]->())
MATCH p2 = (n)-[:has*]->(m) WHERE NOT (m)-[:has]->()
RETURN p,p2;
```

Comment: is there a difference in behaviour if you use exists() instead of the way I did it? I'm not sure I follow the logic.  the second match takes any node found (which includes descendants of nodes that were eliminated but not the eliminated nodes themselves) and finds descendants where the leaf node (at the end of the chain) have no descendants.  that makes no sense to me so I'm going to guess my analysis is incorrect.  furthermore you do two separate matches *and* return both results.  I totally don't understand how this works?

Comment: having had a chance to run it, it doesn't work.  it brings me back the entire tree, nodes that should have been eliminated *and* descendants

Comment: in thinking more about the two step approach I tried this: `MATCH (:Label {Name: 'Root'})-[:has*]->(n) WHERE NOT (n)-[:Exemption]->() AND NOT (n)-[:has]->() return n` but that didn't work either.  I was thinking that if (n) does not exhibit an exemption then we could add to the criteria that (n) also not have descendants... why doesn't that work?